# How to redirect a associated product to its configurable product

Tags: redirect, catalog, configurable-product

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 and I am using the native swatches option. I am trying to only show the associated products on the catalog page and not the configurable product. But I am hoping that by clicking on any of the associated products, it would take the customer to the configurable product.

So lets say that I am selling a cap that has a red and brown option. I want the catalog to show the red simple product and the brown simple product. But when the customer clicks on either of the simple products, it will take them to the configurable product and they can select a color there instead.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an extension that works

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_ForwardToConfigurable

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JRD Redirect Simple to Parent for exactly this. I tried Mestrona as well, but it sets the URL to that of the simple product, which is a problem for bookmarking and the like when the user then changes up the configuration. JRD sets the URL to that of the parent and my plan is to then add a query string so that if the URL is bookmarked, I can route it to the same configured product.